# Make cases smaller

Tags: cases

I have the problem that the cases in my PDF file take a lot of space, which is not necessary. My question is: How can I make:

```
$\begin{cases}
a\\
b\\
c\\
\end{cases}$
```

smaller?

Comment: As always on this size please provide a full but minimal example that otehrs can copy and test on their system. Note that the cases env should _never _ be used in inline math (`$...$`)

Comment: I tried to make it look nice, like it is now, but it does not work like I want. But now is still my question, how can I make it smaller? (Less area on the paper)

Comment: That is not a minimal example, and as already mentioned `cases` should not be uwed in inline math, it belongs in a displayed formua. What you seem to be doing here will be horrible to read.

Comment: And If I use it to display a formula and still think it takes still to much space? Horrible reading is an opinion and it is a private file (just exercises) so i am the only one that must be able to read it.

Comment: If it is an exercise when why is size a problem'

Comment: It is too big in my opinion. And the only thing I am asking for is, does someone know how.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear, what you afer. Some examples, which cross my mind:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
$\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}
            a   &   \\
            b   &   \\
            c   &
        \end{smallmatrix}\right.$ some text
$\medmath{  \begin{cases}
            a   &   \\
            b   &   \\
            c   &   
            \end{cases}}$ some text 
$\begin{cases}
    a   &   \\
    b   &   \\
    c   &
    \end{cases}$ some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that later today (or tomorrow or something like that)